# How do I compile a linux kernel from source to be used in for net booting?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have an old hp laptop running a Pentium 4 Processor, and I need to compile a small sized linux kernel that still has the functionality that I desire (gcc).

I've followed the instructions from [the debian tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall) and have compiled a kernel according to [the arch linux tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation). And now I need to install it.

As far as I can tell I can't just take the image created from compiling the kernel and send that directly to the machine on boot in place of `pxelinux.0`, so what do I need to send over instead?

How/where do I make/find it?

Comment: This site supports Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu, not generic GNU/Linux. You've provided no mention of anything on-topic (only off-topic Linux releases).  Do you need to compile your own kernel? as I have used a pentium 4 box for testing every release up to 19.10  (5.3.0-13 kernel), but I'll provide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel  *Note: Ubuntu 18.04 supports pentium 4, as did 18.10; the last builds were for 19.04; 19.10 does not officially support x86/pentium-4*

Comment: The Ubuntu boot disk barfed at me when I ran it saying my processor was unsupported, the puppy Linux disk doesn't have a reasonable solution for compiling and Linux mint exceeded the 500 MB of RAM

Comment: Did you use the x86/i686/i386 image, a x86_64 image will produce a unsupported message "*This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU*" when I boot an unsuitable ISO in my pentium 4. This is expected; boot the correct image [ie. *architecture*] and it's all good.  Mint & Puppy are *off-topic* here as neither are Ubuntu, or official flavors of Ubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I probably use an x86_64 image, that makes sense, so I'll have to try and get the right one, but that still leaves me trying to net boot the computer since I'm out of DVDs to burn

Comment: Ahh, well, now I can't seem to find other builds of Ubuntu from their site, is there an ftp you're using, or how are you getting you i686 image?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/  but some releases do not have x86 builds. To my knowledge all 19.04/19.10 x86 builds have been deleted (19.10 doesn't support x86 with the 5.3.0-13 being the last x86 build, and is behind my 5.3.0-19 on my current x86_64 box). Lubuntu & Xubuntu were the last desktops to offer 18.10 & (alpha 19.04), but most flavors offered 18.04 LTS in x86.  I've tried Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (gnome) on my pentium 4, and I'd not want to live with it (p4 was underpowered & lighter flavors made way more sense) so I'd opt for Xubuntu or Lubuntu anyway.  x86 is called i386 in debian & Ubuntu

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors  (I download from my ISP's mirror which is on the list, and grab checksum from ubuntu.com to validate it; https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)

Comment: Sweet, now how do I use that iso for a netboot?